# What is the significance of '*' (star, asterisk) in the file listing results?

Tags: filesystem, ls

I have noticed that some of my files have an asterisk at end.

Does the asterisk at the end have any particular significance? I think they are mostly executable and displayed in green by the `ls` command.

You will see that `./bkmp*` and `./bkmp0*` have an asterisk at the end. They are executable bash scripts.

**Here's my output:**

```
drwxr-xr-x 7 username username  4096 Oct  2 18:28 ./
drwxr-xr-x 8 root     root      4096 Oct  2 09:25 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username  3724 Sep 22 03:06 .bashrc
-rwxr--r-- 1 username username   319 Sep 22 03:42 .bkmp*
-rwxr--r-- 1 username username   324 Sep 29 23:30 .bkmp0*
drwx------ 2 username username  4096 Sep 17 13:52 .cache/
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username   675 Sep 17 13:37 .profile
drwx------ 2 username username  4096 Sep 22 10:10 .ssh/
drwx------ 2 username username  4096 Sep 24 19:49 .ssh.local/
drwxr-xr-x 2 username username  4096 Sep 22 04:10 archives/
drwxr-xr-x 3 username username  4096 Sep 24 19:51 home/
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 27511 Sep 24 19:51 username_backup.20120924_1908.tar.gz
```

Comment: for more clarity , could you provide the output ?

Comment: here is a similar question on [su] site. http://superuser.com/q/369955/134448

Comment: on a side note `echo *` has the same output as `ls`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you are just using `ls` with no arguments, it appears that you are using an alias for `ls`. To get the same output, I need to use `ls -lF`. From the `ls` manpage:

```
-F, --classify
          append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries

-l     use a long listing format
```

The symbols mean the following:

```
/: directories
@: symbolic links
|: FIFOs
=: sockets
*: executable files
```

To test if you are using an alias, use `alias ls`. Mine (which is the Ubuntu default) says:

```
$ alias ls
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

More information on using aliases can be found [here](http://www.mediacollege.com/linux/command/alias.html).

Comment: `ll` will do this, as it's an alias of `ls -alF`.

Comment: Just a note, if you want to get rid of the alias, type: unalias ls

Answer (score 6):

Those files are indeed executable. It's because you have (or your `.bashrc` file has) specified the `-F` option. Unfortunately the manpage is not very clear on this:

```
-F, --classify
    append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries
```

But as far as I know `*` is for executables, `/` for directories, `=` for sockets, `>` for doors, `@` for symbolic links, `|` for FIFOs and nothing for regular files.

Also, the colour green is because you have (or your `.bashrc` file has) specified the `--color` option.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your ls is configured to denote executable files.

http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/961288

Maybe your ls is aliased with something extra. check

```
alias ls
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking like they are executables and they starts running if you start your system . something like startup scripts .

Answer (score -1):

- `*`: Install the package with all dependencies.
- `-d`: for access to the service.

Comment: Are you trying to answer a different question? Thi is neither about installing nor about services.